# Basic WITH [alias] AS [query] Error

Tags: mysql, sql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I'm attempting to do a recursive query to get the ancestors of a current child. Although I've read through countless examples, I can't get a single one working. I've also tried to do a basic WITH [alias] AS [query] which throws a 1064 Error. I'm thoroughly confused as this seems extremely basic. I've included both examples below

Basic query:

```
WITH test AS (SELECT * FROM title_hierarchy)
```

Recursive query:

```
WITH results AS
            (
                SELECT  title_id,
                        parent_id
                FROM    title_hierarchy
                WHERE   title_id = 1
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  t.title_id,
                        t.parent_id
                FROM    title_hierarchy t
                        INNER JOIN results r ON r.parent_id = t.title_id
            )
            SELECT  *
            FROM    results
```

Comment: What is the error message

Comment: "*1064 Error*" seems to indicate you are using MySQL. MySQL doesn't support modern SQL like common table expressions.

Comment: That is frustrating. Thanks for the info

Comment: You can always upgrade to Postgres

Answer (score 1):

This is actually not possible in MySQL.